# Simple solution for using 'this' instead of '_this/self/$this' in callback function

Tags: javascript, callback, this

I want to get rid of _this/self/$this helper variable in a callback function. I write:

```
export class someClass {
  someFunction = function( ) {
    this.foo = "bar";
    this.anotherClass.doSomething( this, function( foo ) {
       console.log( this.foo, "/", foo );  // "bar / another bar"
    } );
  }
}
```

and

```
export class anotherClass {
   anotherFoo: string = "another bar";

   doSomething( _this, cb ) {
      cb.call( _this, this.anotherFoo );
   }
}
```

Is there a simpler way to do this? I would like to get rid of the 'this' parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Arrow_functions) to pass the callback:

```
class someClass {
  constructor() {
    this.anotherClass = new anotherClass();
  }

  someFunction() {
    this.foo = "bar";
    this.anotherClass.doSomething(foo => {
      console.log( this.foo, "/", foo );
    });
  }
}

class anotherClass {
  anotherFoo: string = "another bar";

  doSomething(cb) {
    cb(this.anotherFoo);
  }
}
```

Comment: It is a fancy and more readable way of binding the current context to `this`. As for the compiler, nothing changes :)

Comment: @MehmetBaker `.bind()` is really slow, and most JS engines nowadays have native support for arrow functions, which are much faster to create internally.

Comment: I didn't know that, I'll look into it. If this is true then your way is truly the most accurate answer I think :)

Comment: Actually the fastest way seems using `_this`. https://jsperf.com/arrow-function-vs-bind-vs-context-argument/4 So since OP wants more readable code, this way is still better.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your code by using `Function.prototype.bind`

This will allow you to bind a specific context to a function.

For more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

```
export class someClass {
  someFunction = function( ) {
    this.foo = "bar";
    var callback = function(foo) {
      console.log(this.foo, '/', foo);
    };

    this.anotherClass.doSomething(callback.bind(this));
  }
}
```

and

```
export class anotherClass {
  anotherFoo: string = "another bar";

  doSomething(cb) {
    cb(this.anotherFoo);
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to keep the scope in the called function. I just want to have the this value of the calling function in the callback instead of the this value of the called function.

Comment: I couldn't totally figure out what you are trying to do. I have added some code. When someClass calls doSomething, it calls it with someClass' scope. So doSomething in anotherClass will always call the callback with which scope it is binded.

Comment: I understand, but in my case I need the original scope in the doSomething() function. I do not want to change it. Hence the parameter _this. I just had a feeling that there might be a simpler solution, that keeps the this in the called function and keeps it in the callback. But maybe there isn't.

Comment: So I updated my answer. Now the callback function is directly binded to someClass' context. And when it is called via doSomething, it will preserve it's context.

Comment: Yes. That was, what I was looking for.